# Reusing a container or declaring a new one each time

Tags: c++, performance, stl

Suppose you need to use an STL container (set, map, queue) multiple times. Which general approach will be better?

1. Create the container each time.
2. Use the same global object each time, but spend some time clearing it.

```cpp
// Option 1
void foo()
{
    set<int> S; //creating a new S each time foo is called.

    //use S...
}

// Option 2
set<int> S;
void foo()
{
    S.clear();

    //use S...
}
```

Comment: With a node-based it makes little difference, since each node is allocated separately anyway. With a vector you might find a difference.

Comment: If you are going to do this, then make `S` a `static` inside the function.

Comment: "Better" is a bit of an ambiguous term. There are several aspects to consider: runnning time, design clarity, memory consumption, ...

Comment: Also take *multi-threading* into account - with multi-threading any static buffer is probably a very bad idea. You could add mutexes, but then the code becomes way more complex. Just using a non-static variable is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: @KerrekSB ok i get it. one more doubt, is queue node-based?

Comment: @agarwaen: No, the standard queue isn't, since it's backed by a deque. But I don't know if a deque benefits from reuse. You have to test.

Comment: @KerrekSB: agreed you have to test it, but I'd say it's *unlikely* (but not impossible) that `deque` benefits from re-use. The reason I say so is that `deque` doesn't have a capacity, so it would be unexpected for a `deque` to still hog a bunch of resources after calling `clear`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't know... it could hold on to one chunk or something like that. Not sure. If the queue is only used for a few items, then it might be the difference between zero or one allocation.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, it certainly could, but the "obvious" (to me) implementation of `deque` is that it wouldn't, and the questioner doesn't seem interested in any particular implementation. For that matter, holding on to one chunk may or may not be an efficiency gain, depending on the general allocation pattern of the app (what other allocations are made in between calls to this function). It's likely to be, but there is a cost in preventing your program from re-using the most-recently-used memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without doing a performance test, I would tell you that it's intuitive that Options 2 (reuse) is **slightly** faster, because you are not constructing and destructing the container each time. When you destruct the container, it necessarily clears it, otherwise there would be memory leakage.

However, doing a performance test yielding differing results:

- For std::list, it appears that the `clear` takes longer than the
  destructor does.
- For std::set, the results were almost identical.
- For std::map, the results were close, but option 1 (destructor) was
  slightly faster.
- For std::vector, the results were similar to list (even though vector overall is much faster)

So, overall, it appears that option1 is marginally faster. I was running with VS2012, YMMV

Comment: I also might add, that these tests were done using <int> as the stored type. Results could differ significantly if an object type is used.

Comment: For std::queue, the results where almost identical (using int as the stored type). It seems that queue don't benefits from reuse.

Comment: Since that is the case, you should stick with Option 1, as it is thread-safe as option 2 is not

Comment: [For g++ with O2, reuse vector (with `clear`) is much faster than reconstruct them](https://tio.run/##nVFNb4IwGD7TX9G4gxAiKtlJqhfjaUtc5o5LSC1Fm0FL@uFhC399rAUVSLbLuEDfPp8vpKpmJ0Ka5oFxUpiMIiaUlhSXG3AfXSjRQg4G5CwFFxsALNQQDUuKlZH0C3iZMMeCQmXK9SJhXENu38BTOlutSCHIR6qh0ljqVLOS2puLYFk38QPL9/rLdU/yA4us72BRXbGmDEeo2UjaC0M@4Elaid7FkYTRCE1gCN8sYQUnCPlWcs6D@fZ5v306pC@71/Sw2yI0fefTVqpOAHC1LM5@XXvDfGlPrUm@bA3sILqWurXvlogseQOxHeZC@k6JuUWhx4V9kjBkAY4qo87pEdtCrGW7ljhS7JO2ap2220EC6kGG2Gb4zanLFXe54mEuHJGCYtmp/jtOPIrjNErMeGc3El3eNN2Skr9v43vN2y@72vTHGjTNN8kLfFLNbB//AA). Can you post your benchmark code?

Comment: Your performance test is pretty meaningless or even misleading, if you do not share the type and number of elements you stored. For example filling a vector using `push_back()` is going to be significantly faster if it is preallocated. How many reallocations will happen depends on how many elements you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not going to have to deal with multithreading issues, case 2 is probably better.  Mainly because for some standard lib containers clear avoids memory allocation.  Specifically look at the documentation for [std::vector's clear function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/).

Clear doesn't cause memory reallocation, the capacity of the vector is unchanged.

Comment: Not dealing with multi-threading is necessary but not sufficient condition for case 2 to be correct. There are other forms of re-entrancy than threads, recursive calls being the most obvious :-)